# Webcam not working on Thinkpad Lenovo X1 Nano Gen 2 - Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04, thinkpad, webcam, cheese

Just switched to Ubuntu from Windows and it seems like the webcam has issues. Here are my **hardware specs**:

```
Hardware: Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Nano Gen 2
Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1260P × 16
Graphics: Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
```

output of **v4l2-ctl**:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/video0

ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/media0
```

output of **dmesg**:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i usb             
[    0.007388] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008F808000 000E54 (v02 LENOVO UsbCTabl 00001000 INTL 20200717)
[    0.265597] ACPI: USB4 _OSC: OS supports USB3+ DisplayPort+ PCIe+ XDomain+
[    0.265598] ACPI: USB4 _OSC: OS controls USB3+ DisplayPort+ PCIe+ XDomain+
[    1.061849] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.061849] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.061849] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.061849] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.212977] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.212992] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.213004] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.573186] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.576295] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.576298] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.576339] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.576342] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.576343] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.576345] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.576346] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.576570] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.579468] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.579472] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.579473] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.579474] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.579475] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.579585] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.579921] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.746972] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.748778] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.748787] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0d.0: Host supports USB 3.2 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.748965] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.748977] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.748983] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.748987] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.748991] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.749424] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.750796] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.750804] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.750807] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.750810] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.750813] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.751840] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.917603] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.073866] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8074, bcdDevice=93.05
[    2.073877] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.073886] usb 1-3: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[    2.073893] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[    2.075297] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.205689] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.237976] usb 4-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.262182] usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8073, bcdDevice=93.05
[    2.262198] usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.262204] usb 4-3: Product: USB3.1 Hub
[    2.262208] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[    2.265257] hub 4-3:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.356955] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=00bd, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    2.356971] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[    2.356977] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: ab3c9bd2a845
[    2.457583] usb 1-3.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.565756] usb 4-3.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.586556] usb 4-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=6000, bcdDevice=32.01
[    2.586572] usb 4-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.586578] usb 4-3.1: Product: USB-C Dual-4K Dock
[    2.586582] usb 4-3.1: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[    2.586586] usb 4-3.1: SerialNumber: DGWC00110032634
[    2.600638] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    2.623982] cdc_ncm 4-3.1:1.5 eth0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:0d.0-3.1, CDC NCM, 80:6d:97:3d:54:35
[    2.625058] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    2.714045] usb 4-3.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.846895] usb 4-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8075, bcdDevice= 6.65
[    2.846911] usb 4-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.846917] usb 4-3.2: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[    2.846922] usb 4-3.2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[    2.847050] usb 1-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8076, bcdDevice= 6.60
[    2.847066] usb 1-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.847072] usb 1-3.2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.847076] usb 1-3.2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[    2.848851] hub 1-3.2:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.850419] hub 4-3.2:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.969694] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.121337] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=0b63, bcdDevice=10.02
[    3.121352] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.121358] usb 1-8: Product: USB Bridge
[    3.121363] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: MCHP
[    3.245951] usb 4-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.249729] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.269394] usb 4-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8073, bcdDevice=93.05
[    3.269410] usb 4-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.269416] usb 4-3.4: Product: USB3.1 Hub
[    3.269420] usb 4-3.4: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[    3.273290] hub 4-3.4:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.401435] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0033, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    3.401451] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.411253] ljca 1-8:1.0: LJCA USB device init success
[    3.411283] usbcore: registered new interface driver ljca
[    3.505711] usb 1-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.633347] usb 1-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=8074, bcdDevice=93.05
[    3.633365] usb 1-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.633371] usb 1-3.4: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[    3.633375] usb 1-3.4: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
[    3.635726] hub 1-3.4:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.709814] usb 1-3.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    3.815040] usb 1-3.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=065f, idProduct=f60f, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    3.815056] usb 1-3.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.815062] usb 1-3.2.3: Product: SD4750P USB-C & USB 3.0 Dual 4K Docking Station
[    3.815067] usb 1-3.2.3: Manufacturer: Good way
[    3.815070] usb 1-3.2.3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABC
[    3.836590] hid-generic 0003:065F:F60F.0005: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Good way SD4750P USB-C & USB 3.0 Dual 4K Docking Station] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2.3/input0
[    3.836631] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.836633] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.961710] usb 1-3.4.3: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[    4.091119] usb 1-3.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=00cb, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    4.091125] usb 1-3.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.091127] usb 1-3.4.3: Product: Microsoft USB Optical Mouse
[    4.091128] usb 1-3.4.3: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    4.097877] input: PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4.3/1-3.4.3:1.0/0003:045E:00CB.0006/input/input9
[    4.098489] hid-generic 0003:045E:00CB.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4.3/input0
[    4.575603] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[    4.588709] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_mbim
[    4.691465] usb 4-3.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
[    4.691468] usb 4-3.1: [4] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 2, val = -4592/7680/16
[    4.698985] usb 4-3.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=672), cval->res is probably wrong.
[    4.698989] usb 4-3.1: [7] FU [USB Audio Playback Volume] ch = 6, val = -10752/0/16
[    4.699157] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    4.726894] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    8.509763] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
[ 1269.652358] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

permissions of **/dev/video0**:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Feb  7 10:23 /dev/video0
```

when I test the cam using cheese I get the following **error**:

```
cheese -d /dev/video0                
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2216: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.

(cheese:8934): Gdk-WARNING **: 11:00:21.497: Native Windows taller than 65535 pixels are not supported

(cheese:8934): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:00:21.578: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8934): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:00:21.696: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8934): cheese-WARNING **: 11:00:21.709: Device '/dev/video0' does not support 2:0:0:0 colourimetry: ../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2object.c(4105): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Device wants 2:0:0:0 colorimetry
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Try using `guvcview` instead of `cheese`?

Comment: I'm using cheese just for testing, I need the webcam for meetings and doesn't work at all

Comment: Yes, I understand. Please, try guvcview. Does it work? Cheese doesn't always work with some webcams.

Comment: is cheese a snap package?
$snap list

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg,width=640,height=360,framerate=30/1' ! avdec_mjpeg ! videoconvert ! ximagesink